# How can a notation exist for ObjectNode?

Tags: uml

As UML 2.5 defines, ObjectNode is an abstract class. For my understanding, an abstract class can not be instantiated.

So why is there a graphical notation for ObejctNode since it could not be instantiated in a schema ? See figure 15.49 of UML specification.

Comment: great, someone add 1 to my question, is there a way to see who and why ? it is a bit weird that one can up/down vote without posting any comment to advocate his choice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why couldn't it?

If an abstract class defines a notation then that simply means that this is the notation used by all subclasses, unless they define their own notation, overriding the notation of the (abstract) parent class.

Although not explicitly mentioned it seems like this is rather similar to the notation of a classifier.
From the UML 2.5 specs:

> 9.2.4.1 Classifiers
>
> Classifier is an abstract metaclass. It is nevertheless convenient to define in one place a default notation available for
>   any concrete subclass of Classifier. Some specializations of Classifier have their own distinct notations.

Another similar construct has been used for the abstract meta-class Action:

> 16.2.4.1 Actions
>
> Actions are notated as round-cornered rectangles, as shown in Figure 16.2. The name of the action or other description
>   of it may appear in the symbol. (Specialized notations for certain specific kinds of Actions are described in subsequent
>   sub clauses.)
>
> [image]

Comment: ok but what could be the meaning to model an abstract "meta-class" ? Something like "now I do not know what concrete class to use and later or somewhere else I defined the concrete meta-class to use ?

Comment: And do you have a reference of what you suggested ? In the specification this is not written. The graphical representation of a meta-class does not seem to be a property of the meta-class, so why meta-classes which extend one should use the same graphical notation by default ?

Comment: You can't model an abstract meta-class, only it's concrete subclasses. But they all inherit the properties of the abstract meta-class. If you see the notation as a property of the meta-class that can be inherited then that makes sense. I don't know if or where that is described in the specs. You might have to look in the meta-specs.

Comment: I checked the UML specification and the MOF specification, no where I read that the notation is a property of a meta-class. And if it is not possible to model an abstract meta-class, figure  15.49 should not be here ...

Comment: Isn't that it the most logical explanation? Or do you expect the UML specs to repeat the notation for each individual sub-meta-class, even if all of them have the same notation? Any other explanation, including the assumption that ObjectNode would not be abstract seems a bit far fetched.

Comment: @Bellekens, i did not say that your explanation is not logic, it could be. But we can expect that the specification contains all details and that something inherited by extending classes is defined as a property ... And it seems that we agree to say that figure 15.49 is not possible since it is not possible to model an abstrat class. As you, i would never suggest that ObjectNode is not an abstrac class : the specification says that's one ...

Comment: No I don't thinks the figure is incorrect. Since all object nodes share the same notation there is no way to know which subtype of ObjectNode is show on the example figure. I've added some more info to my answer that might help clear this up. I do agree that it would have been better to explicitly explain the notation like they do for Classifier.

Comment: @Bellekens, your extract of specification is meaningful, and the comment of figure 15.14 "goes" in your way: it is the same to use to use an ObjectNode and two object flows than iput/output pin and an object flow ... A bit confusing but why not.

Answer (score -2):

@granier, you are right for me it is a typo in the UML 2.5 spec. Objectode can definetly be instanciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a typo. If you read the explanation it get mentioned lots of times, including a list of concrete sub meta classes.

Comment: I agree on the fact that ObjectNode can be instanciated. But figure 15.49 shows ObjectNode metaclasse in italique which means that is abstract and can not be instanciated that is the typo. Same for figure 1 with Element, RelationShip And Comment. Element and Relationship meta classes are in italique so they can not be instanciated. Comment, a sub metaclasse of Element, is not in italique so it is not abstract so it can be instanciated.

Comment: So you base that statement on the implicit reasoning that if there is a figure in the specs showing an ObjectNode they must be concrete. But you choose to ignore several explicit statements that ObjectNode is abstract?